# Math Olympiad (Number Theory) solution verification

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, contest-math

> Let $n,p > 1$ be positive integers and $p$ be prime. Given that $n \mid p−1$ and $p \mid n^3 −1$, prove that $4p − 3$ is a perfect square.

Iran 2005

My solution;

$n \mid p−1 \implies kn + 1 = p\tag{1}$

$p \mid  n^3 −1 \implies p \mid n^2 + n + 1$ (as $ p \ge n + 1 > n-1.$)

Putting (1) in the above equation implies;

$$ nk + 1 \mid n^2 + n + 1 +\ [+(k-1)n - (k-1)n] \\\implies nk + 1 \mid n + 1 - k \\\implies |n + 1 - k| \ge nk + 1$$

Case 1 : $ n + 1 - k > 0$

Then, $n \ge n(k+1)$ which is not possible.

Case 2: $ n + 1 - k < 0$

Then, $ k \ge n(k+1) + 2$ which is also not possible,

Hence $ n + 1 - k = 0$

Putting this into (1) $\implies p=n^2 + n + 1 \implies 4p-3 = (2n+1)^2$

I read through my solution and everything seems to check out, but I have never done the splitting into two cases thing before so I am just suspicious about that.

Could you please tell me if my proof is correct and checks out,

Thanks!

Comment: When you post a question like this you should always specify what step of the proof you have doubts about. Else it add little value to the site.

Comment: @BillDubuque , I had specified that my suspicion was about the 'splitting into two cases thing'; next time, I will write that more prominently.

Comment: But why are you suspicious about that (and what do you mean by that)? You will likely get more helpful answers if you make that clear. You shouldn't accept an answer that doesn't address that if that is where your doubt lies (once you accept many users won't even open the page).

Comment: @BillDubuque , ok! I will keep that in mind next time, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution looks good.

To avoid (explicitly) splitting into two cases, you could simply say that $|n + 1 - k| \leq \max(n, k) < nk + 1$ and hence $n + 1 - k = 0$.